# How to make installer using installshield

Tags: visual-c++, visual-studio-2012, installshield

I developed windows service in visual c++ using VS2012. Usually I install it using sc create .... command for testing purpose. Now i want to create installer for my service using install shield limited. How can I do that? can anyone show me the steps to do that.

Thanks,
Khurram.

Answer (score 0):

I guess your best bet is try to look up some InstallShield IDE tutorials as the installation package is created in a standalone IDE, but from my experience with InstallShield, Nullsoft and others I would recommend you take a look at WIX (http://wixtoolset.org/), it integrates with Visual Studio, creates a fully functioning MSI package and it is easy to do things like installing a service - take a look at an example here: [How to install and start a Windows Service using WiX](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1942039/how-to-install-and-start-a-windows-service-using-wix).