# How to install and start a windows service with wix installer?

Tags: .net, service, wix, windows-installer

How can I install a windows service with WiX? I already did everything on the setup to install a normal .exe but what musst I do to install and start a service? 
Do I only need to [copy this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1943167/10318818) in my product.wxs and everything will work?
 
I want to install it via the Setup and set the Service to autostart on Windows Startup. And I want to delete the Service with the Setup mean it will stop the Service and uninstall it. It would be great to if I can update the Service too with a new Setup mean it will stop the Service, uninstall it, install the new one and start it.
Is all this possible with the Code from the answere I linked?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

***"Hello Service"***: The markup you link to should generally work, but it is a bit involved and complex. You can normally get away with fewer constructs. Here is a full-featured, self-contained practical example on github: [How to create a Windows Service MSI Installer Using WiX](https://github.com/Robs79/How-to-create-a-Windows-Service-MSI-Installer-Using-WiX) (I didn't actually test it, but it looks good).

***IsWiX***: Chris Painter also has a sample on how to install services: https://github.com/iswix-llc/iswix-tutorials/tree/master/windows-service

***Documentation***: [ServiceInstall](http://wixtoolset.org/documentation/manual/v3/xsd/wix/serviceinstall.html), [ServiceControl](http://wixtoolset.org/documentation/manual/v3/xsd/wix/servicecontrol.html).