# How to override the server with now installer in visual studio installer 2015

Tags: visual-studio, windows-installer, setup-project, vsinstaller

I need to override the older version of installer form newer version.I am using installer for installing the windows services.
Visual Studio Installer 2015.

I change the installer with property **"RemovePreviousVersion"= true**, But in the installer getting error because service is not uninstalled and try to override this.

Error 1001. An exception occurred in the OnAfterInstall event handler of System.ServiceProcess.ServiceInstaller --CouslNot Star service on computer

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EVK6W.png)

Comment: You have to stop the service.  You can go to Control Panel Services and stop service, or in Task Manager kill the process the service is running.

Comment: This is installer, User will not go and stop the service.

Comment: Do a google for following.  Lots of hits : "msdn Visual Studio installer stop service"

Comment: Rewrote first section of answer below. Please have a look at the 3-4 first paragraphs (including the limits of VS Installer projects).

Answer (score 1):

> ***Short Answer / Suggestion***: Services must be stopped before install / uninstall / upgrade operations. There are mechanisms built into MSI to do so.
> [Hotlink to show how this is done using WiX](https://github.com/Robs79/How-to-create-a-Windows-Service-MSI-Installer-Using-WiX/blob/master/WindowsService.Installer/Product.wxs#L34) ([`ServiceInstall`](https://wixtoolset.org/documentation/manual/v3/xsd/wix/serviceinstall.html)
> and [`ServiceControl`](https://wixtoolset.org/documentation/manual/v3/xsd/wix/servicecontrol.html) elements).
>
> [Here is a proposed WiX quick start](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25004226/msi-vs-nuget-packages-which-are-is-better-for-continuous-delivery/25005864#25005864) (with lots of link noise to
> all kinds of WiX and MSI topics - it is an ad-hoc organically growing
> link answer).
>
> - [Hello WiX](http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/105638/A-quick-introduction-Create-an-MSI-installer-with)
> - [Hello WiX Visual Studio Votive](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47970743/wix-installer-msi-not-installing-the-winform-app-created-with-visual-studio-2017/47972615#47972615) (maybe check markup at bottom first)

---

***WiX***: [Use a proper deployment tool](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50225031/windows-service-not-shown-in-add-remove-programs-under-control-panel/50229840#50229840) is the best advice, for example WiX. Visual Studio installer projects are known to be inflexible and have limitations for service installation among [many other problems](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47936435/visual-studio-publish-project-into-one-simple-installer/47944893#47944893) ([shorter, list form](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2635671/why-use-windows-installer-xml-wix-over-vdproj/2637666#2637666)).

Specifically in this case you need to use custom actions to start and stop services (unless there are new constructs in the latest Visual Studio installer projects that I am not familiar with - I don't think there are). [Custom actions are complex and error prone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46179778/why-is-it-a-good-idea-to-limit-the-use-of-custom-actions-in-my-wix-msi-setups/46179779#46179779). Proper MSI tools use built-in MSI constructs to make service installation more reliable.

***Post-Processing***: Some people post-process their MSI using [Orca or equivalent tools](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48482545/how-can-i-compare-the-content-of-two-or-more-msi-files/48482546#48482546) to add constructs to the [ServiceInstall](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/msi/serviceinstall-table), [ServiceControl](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/msi/servicecontrol-table) tables after building the MSIs with Visual Studio Installer Projects. Not rocket science, but a hassle and not recommended.

***ServiceInstall*** & ***ServiceControl***: Essentially you need to author the [ServiceInstall](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/msi/serviceinstall-table) and [ServiceControl](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/msi/servicecontrol-table) tables so that the service is installed, started, stopped and uninstalled in an operational manner. Only a few combinations here really make sense. Such as to stop on uninstall and stop and start on install.

- [How to install and start a Windows Service using WiX](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1942039/how-to-install-and-start-a-windows-service-using-wix)

***WiX Samples***: [**WiX quick start suggestions here**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25004226/msi-vs-nuget-packages-which-are-is-better-for-continuous-delivery/25005864#25005864) and some WiX samples of service installation:

- https://github.com/Robs79/How-to-create-a-Windows-Service-MSI-Installer-Using-WiX
- https://github.com/iswix-llc/iswix-tutorials/tree/master/windows-service

---

***Advanced Installer***: And two links for commercial tool Advanced Installer on service installations. Don't underestimate commercial tools as relevant for you. *"Some tools are free only if your time is worthless"*. WiX is great, but can be hard to learn and always takes time:

- https://www.advancedinstaller.com/installing-windows-services.html
- https://www.advancedinstaller.com/user-guide/qa-install-service.html