# How to Electron builder MSI install/register windows service

Tags: electron, nsis, electron-builder

I want to install my windows service with my electron builder MSI

Using NSIS I am able to include "build/installer.nsh" using installer.nsh  I am able to call windows service EXE after NSIS EXE install.... but there is no option in MSI to include "build/installer.nsh" so is there a way to call other EXE/MSI from electron builder MSI or other way to install windows service exe from electron builder MSI

Package FIle

```
"win": {
      "target": [
        "nsis",
        "msi"
      ],
      "certificateFile": "C:\\SVN\\mancrossplatform\\trunk\\mcs.pfx",
      "certificatePassword": "",
      "publisherName": "",
      "requestedExecutionLevel": "asInvoker",
      "signAndEditExecutable": true,
      "signDlls": true
    },
    "nsis": {
      "oneClick": true,
      "perMachine": false,
      "deleteAppDataOnUninstall": true,
      "createDesktopShortcut": true,
      "include": "build/installer.nsh"
    },
    "extraFiles": [
      "software"
    ],
    "msi": {
      "oneClick": true,
      "perMachine": true,
      "createDesktopShortcut": true
    },
    "files": [
      "resources",
      "dist/",
      "dist/main.prod.js",
      "dist/main.prod.js.map",
      "package.json"
    ],
    "directories": {
      "buildResources": "resources",
      "output": "release"
    }
```

Comment: Ankur, did you find a solution for your question?

Comment: Yes using the WIX installer.. in Wix, you can install the windows server https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1942039/how-to-install-and-start-a-windows-service-using-wix