# Creating an installer for a windows service on Visual Studio 2022

Tags: c#, visual-studio, service

typically I don't work with VS and C#, but my company requires it for this project. So kinda new on this stuff.

I got some code from a previous developer, which is just a .net service doing some stuff. Som adjustment had been done in the code my me, not a problem at this point.

But here comes the trick: I need to create an installer, .exe or .msi file, which installs the service on the windows machine where it get's executed. I tried so much, googled my ass off but nothing did the work for me.

Is there anyone that can help and explain, step for step, what I need to do in VS?

Very much thanks in advance!

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/windows-services/walkthrough-creating-a-windows-service-application-in-the-component-designer#add-installers-to-the-service

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I already tried this one. Describes it pretty good. But it does not tell me, how to create an installer for a different machine

Answer (score 5):

I highly recommend the WiX Toolset to create an MSI for installing a Windows service.  [This tutorial](https://cmartcoding.com/creating-a-windows-service-and-installer-using-net-and-wix/) takes you through the process from end-to-end, including setting up your development environment for WiX.  You can see their [service install documentation](https://wixtoolset.org/documentation/manual/v3/howtos/general/install_windows_service.html) for a high-level overview.  Also, [this StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1942039/how-to-install-and-start-a-windows-service-using-wix) is an excellent resource.

If you run into issues, I'm happy to help address them.